# add a text link into appended array from php to AJAX

Tags: jquery

I am making a live search where when user type in a search box, results start showing up inside a table. A `<td>` of this table should display the result as a text link.

I have this `AJAX` script:

```
success:function(res)
    {
      $("#patient_name_table tr").fadeOut(500);
      $.each( res, function( key, row ) {
              //alert(row['patient_name']);
              $("#after_tr_2").after("<tr><td>"+row['patient_name']+"</td></tr>");
            });
    },
```

Results are shown properly, but when I tried to add an `<a href>` to it like:

```
success:function(res)
    {
      $("#patient_name_table tr").fadeOut(500);
      $.each( res, function( key, row ) {
              //alert(row['patient_name']);
              $("#after_tr_2").after("<tr><td><a href='patients.php?patient='"+row['patient_name']+"></a></td></tr>");
            });
    },
```

I have the same exact row shown but clickable text is like hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just forget to close the a tag `'>` and remove the `'` before the `"+row` Replace. To Show text insert `row['patient_name']` into the `<a></a>` tags

```
 $("#after_tr_2").after("<tr><td><a href='patients.php?patient='"+row['patient_name']+"</a></td></tr>");
```

with

```
 $("#after_tr_2").after("<tr><td><a href='patients.php?patient="+row['patient_name']+"'>" + row['patient_name']  + "</a></td></tr>");
```

If the patient name is `GoodPatient` the html out put is

```
<tr><td><a href='patients.php?patient=GoodPatient'>GoodPatient</a></td></tr>
```

and this should be fine.

Comment: No, still the same, I have the `>` in my code but some way it was missing here in my question

Comment: Kordi's answer is correct but he forgot the closing `'`' for the `href` attribute.

Comment: @Utkanos fixed it, in the moment you wrote your comment .. Thanks a lot for the note if I didn't get it!

Comment: Oh okay, I added the `'` but still the same problem

Comment: @androidnation and you have to remove the one `'` before the "+row. Updated my answer!

Comment: And I should add between `'>"` and `</a>` again `=row['patient_name']` to show a text. Thanks alot now it is working